# Existence of an orthogonal basis with respect to a given set of matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces, linear-transformations, change-of-basis

Consider a complex vector subspace $W \subset V$ such that $\mathrm{dim}W = n$. Suppose I have a set $S$ of $n$ linearly independent complex matrices $S = \{ M_1, \cdots, M_n\}$ that act on $V$.

Let $w$ be some non-zero vector in $W$ and consider
$$
w_1' = M_1w, \quad w_2' = M_2 w, \quad \cdots \quad w_n'= M_n w. 
$$
Is it always possible to choose a non-zero vector $w$ so that $w_1', \cdots, w_n'$ is a mutually orthogonal basis for $W$ with respect to the standard complex inner product? If so, is it possible to construct $w$?

(If linear independence is not strong enough, can we find such a $w$ if $S$ is instead mutually orthogonal with respect to the trace inner product $\langle A, B \rangle = \mathrm{Tr}(A^\dagger B)$?)

Comment: Here, linear independence doesn't mean anything special? Just that $\sum_{j=1}^n c_jM_j=0$ implies $c_1=\ldots=c_n=0$?

You probably don't care about the solution $w=0$.

Comment: @user469053 Yeah good point, I am only looking for non-trivial solutions

Comment: We can construct examples where the column spaces are all in a single line, so $w_1',\ldots, w_n'$ all have to be in that same line. For example, pick any $0\neq x\in \mathbb{C}^2$. Let $$M_1=\begin{pmatrix} x & x \end{pmatrix} $$ $$M_2= \begin{pmatrix} x & .5 x\end{pmatrix}.$$

Comment: @user469053 My bad, I guess I should also say I want the image to span $W$, i.e., I want $w_1', \cdots, w_n'$ to be an orthogonal basis for $W$